# Oledb exception was unhandled. Operation must use an updateable query

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I am trying insert values into excel sheet and when I am debugging its showing thaat OLedb exception was unhandled. Operation must use an updateable query.
Here is my code

```
 string sql = "";
 sql = sql + " Insert into [Sheet1$] (ph1, type1, lines1, ph2, type2, lines2, ph3, type3, lines3, ph4, type4, lines4, stdcode) values ('" + PhoneNumbers[i, 0] + "','" + PhoneNumbers[i, 1] + "','" .........+ "','" + PhoneNumbers[i, 11] + "','" + PhoneNumbers[i, 12] + "'); ";
  System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
                    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();

                    MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"");
                    MyConnection.Open();
                    myCommand.Connection = MyConnection;

                    myCommand.CommandText = sql;
                    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MyConnection.Close();
```

Can someone tell me how to inser data without getting this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your application dosen't have permission to write to the excel file.
check if the file is readonly and change it to be with read/write access.

Comment: is has all the permissions

Comment: and the folder where the file located in also not in readonly?